# Claims Stored in Cookies Exceed Max Request Header Length

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 website using the vanilla implementation for authentication/authorization using Identity and cookies (not using OpenID Connect). I have a set of 20 roles, each of which could potentially have hundreds of claims used to permission access to site pages/features (using Authorize to decorate controller methods). I want to be able to control access to these pages/features without recompiling the site every time a change is needed; instead I allow admins to add/remove role claims directly through the site. For some reason I am hitting a ceiling based on the number of claims projected onto the user's identity.

I'm receiving an error

```
HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long
```

Any idea why I would be receiving this message? What is the best practice store/access these claims to be used with authorization?

Comment: The best practice for claims is not to make them too fine-grained. They should map to **roles** that each application interprets for it's own use. These is nothing you can do about the request header size because it is usually defined in the HTTP handling hardware.

Comment: What kind of data are you storing in claims? If it's just roles, it would take a hella lot to butt up against a request header limits. Consider shuffling some of that off to your actual user entity if you can. Not every thing should or needs to be a claim.

Comment: I'm just using it for role permissions, which when projected onto the user Identity was about 150 claims, which I would think is well within the limits. This expanded the number of chunked cookies to 4 chunks; again, I would think would be well within the limits. Would messing with chunk size be advisable?

Comment: No, the limit you're hitting is total headers size. 150 claims is way too many. The fall back plan for huge identities is cookieAuthOptions.SessionStore. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/CookieSessionSample/Startup.cs

Comment: Just stumbled upon this thread. The sample on Github mentioned by @Tratcher is now here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/samples/CookieSessionSample

Comment: Also, here's an SO answer which provides code to filter out claims you're not interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314443/why-doesnt-claims-transformation-reduce-the-cookie-size#51331946

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem on a Windows server.  I had to resort to a registry setting.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

MaxFieldLength (DWORD) Decimal value 65534

MaxRequestBytes (DWORD) Decimal value 16777216

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows

Comment: I did the above but I'm still getting the error. I have about 70 odd claims.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is resolved by Configuring CookieAuthenticationOptions to use Session Store.
The following link explains "Auth Cookies in ASP.NET Core" and its configuration options in detail

[Click Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/using-auth-cookies-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: This sloved my problem. There was more then 4 chunk of cookie which increases request size to 16 000 bytes and exceds the limits. Now requests are around 1000 Bytes