# Why doesn't claims transformation reduce the cookie size?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD (.net core 2.1) and have registered my app and configured it to return AD groups as claims. I am also using claims transformation to remove all group claims other than the three groups that my app uses, which successfully eliminates over 100 groups. I did this hoping that it would reduce the size of the cookie in subsequent request headers, but this does not appear to be the case.

Whether I use the claims transformation or not, the cookie size is the same:
[image: Cookie Size]

I know that the claims transformation is working, because I have a simple page that iterates the claims in a list, and it correctly shows only the three groups when I have the filter in place.

As a result of the large cookie, I am getting HTTP 400 - Request too long. I can work around this by modifying the registry on the web server (as suggested elsewhere https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020943/http-400-bad-request-request-header-too-long-response-to-http-request), but my real question is what is the point of filtering the claims if the size of the cookie remains unchanged?

I would also be interested to know if there is an app setting that I could use to increase the max header size, to avoid having to modify the registry.

I'm not sure if the code is really relevant here, but here are a few snippets:

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
        var identity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity != null)
        {
            var unused = identity.FindAll(GroupsToRemove).ToList();
            unused.ForEach(c => identity.TryRemoveClaim(c));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
}
```

The filter is registered as a singleton in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, FilterGroupClaimsTransformation>();
```

Comment: This will only remove claims from the ClaimsPrincipal already set on the request (e.g. `HttpContext.User`).  It has no impact on the cookie because it is run after the cookie has been loaded by the authentication handler.  The contents of the cookie can only be changed immediately after sign-in.  Have a look into the `Events` when configuring your authentication handler (in Startup).  There should be an event you can use to perform your filtering and reduce the cookie size.

Comment: Yes I was able to filter using the `OnSigningIn` event when calling `.AddCookie()` and that reduced the cookie size as desired. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Brad answered the question as to why the cookie size did not change by using claims transformation. Here is the code I used to reduce the cookie size, thanks to his suggestion:

In Startup.cs, ConfigureServices()...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(...)
       .AddCookie(options => options.Events.OnSigningIn = FilterGroupClaims);
}

private static Task<ClaimsPrincipal> FilterGroupClaims(CookieSigningInContext context)
{
    var principal = context.Principal;
    if (principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var unused = identity.FindAll(GroupsToRemove).ToList();
        unused.ForEach(c => identity.TryRemoveClaim(c));
    }
    return Task.FromResult(principal);
}

private static bool GroupsToRemove(Claim claim)
{
    string[] _groupObjectIds = new string[] { };    // pull from config or whereever
    return claim.Type == "groups" && !_groupObjectIds.Contains(claim.Value);
}
```

For my end solution, I moved the static methods inside another class, but I kept everything inline here for brevity.
Cookie size reduced from 6 chunks to 2 with this method.

Comment: You can set the `EventsType` property to a class that inherits from `CookieAuthenticationEvents`.  This results in a solution that supports dependency injection and you only need override the event handlers you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

For everything that has to do with Identity we must use the Authorization Cookie
using this form, it did not work for me, because it never entered the event `OnSigningIn`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(...)
       .AddCookie(options => options.Events.OnSigningIn = FilterGroupClaims);
}
```

But it inspired me and this form did work for me, it eliminates the claims that I don't need and reduces the Cookie size.

In Startup.cs, `ConfigureServices()`:

```
//Solved
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSigningIn = async (signinContext) =>
    {
        var principal = signinContext.Principal;
        var identity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    
        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims.ToList())
        {
            if (claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role &&
                !claim.Value.StartsWith(claim_prefix_to_remove_applicationPrefix)
            {
                identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
            }
        }
    };
});
```